# display values of checkbox in the iterative table angular 8

Tags: angular

1. I am not able to iterate my table
2. I am not able to get checkbox values, only getting true false values
   my checkboxes

inside template-

```
  <label class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let day of days">
      <input
       type="checkbox"
       formControlName="{{ day.name }}"
       name="{{ day.name }}"/>
       {{ day.value }}
  </label>
```

inside TS file

```
  days: any = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "repeat_sun",
      isActive: false,

      value: "Sun"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "repeat_mon",
      isActive: false,

      value: "Mon"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "repeat_tue",
      isActive: false,

      value: "Tue"
    }

  ];
```

template:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>

     <th scope="col">days</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- selected day -->
   <td></td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5n6ff6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot the `value` attribute:

```
 <input type="checkbox"
              formControlName="{{ day.name }}"
              value="{{day.value}}"
              name="{{ day.name }}" />{{ day.value }}
```

2. Here's an example of iterating your employees inside the after-submit `forTableArray`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of forTableArray.employee">
      <td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{employee.lastName}}</td>
      <td>
        <span *ngFor="let skill_exp of employee.skills">
          {{skill_exp.skill}} {{skill_exp.exp}}
        </span>
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: it works, but i only get values as true false, i am trying to display selected checkbox value, sun,tue,mon